# Add a hyperlink underneath the table of a Page View?

Tags: views, hooks, 7

I have a Page View that is being displayed as a table. Underneath that table I want to add a simple hyperlink.

I was looking into `hook_views_pre_render` but I do not see any way to do add this. I also tried `hook_preprocess_node`. In order to add an anchor tag underneath the table, I really don't know if I should be looking at view hooks or page hooks, or ?

Question:
How do I add a hyperlink underneath the table of a Page View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do that.

1. Edit View
2. Click "Footer > Add"
3. Add your footer HTML as "Global: Text Area"

Another way is to add a block on that page under the view.

1. admin/structure/block/add
2. Set page visibility to only your View page path
3. Set region to "Content" below "Main page content"

If you want more control or placement, you can theme the View page

1. Edit the View
2. Click "Advanced > Theme > Information"
3. You would override the page level "[views-view.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7)" template renamed to match your View (e.g views-view--my-view.tpl.php ) in your theme dir.

Comment: The block approach fit my situation. Thanks for taking the time David.